# When running an ansible playbook via a shell script in Jenkins pipeline, the echo output is buffered and does not show in real time

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

So below I have attached my pipeline code for Jenkins. The runansible.sh script takes in the parameters given and then proceeds to run an ansible playbook based on the `paramMode` value. When kicking off the shell script in a terminal I get realtime output of the ansible playbook running, but when using the Jenkins pipeline I just get the loading cogwheel during the echo stage. I do not get any echo output until the whole playbook has completed and then it spits it out all at once. I need to be able to have live output from the playbook like I do in a terminal so the progress can be monitored as the build is building. What do I need to do to get realtime output?

```
def paramMode = "${params.mode}"
def paramClientCode = "${params.client_code}"
def paramPrevCodeDropID = "${params.prev_code_drop_id}"
def paramCodeDropID = "${params.code_drop_id}"
def paramReleaseID = "${params.release_id}"
def paramConfigZipVer = "${params.config_zip_ver}"
def paramEmailIDs = "${params.email_ids}"

node {
    stage('one-click') {
        node ('nodeName') {
            git url: "gitURL", branch: "runParallel", credentialsId: "stash_id"
            echo sh (returnStdout: true, script: """
            ./runansible.sh ${paramMode} -h ${paramClientCode} -c ${paramCodeDropID} -r ${paramReleaseID} -v ${paramConfigZipVer} -e ${paramEmailIDs} -p ${paramPrevCodeDropID}
            """)

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is already the default behavior of `sh`, but you have disabled it by using `returnStdout: true`. This causes the output to be captured and returned, instead of printed. Then you print it with `echo`.

From the [documentation of `sh`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script):

> returnStdout (optional)
>
> If checked, standard output from the task is
>   returned as the step value as a String, rather than being printed to
>   the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the
>   log.)

So instead of `echo sh (returnStdout:true, ...)` try just `sh (...)`

Comment: This was the solution. I had to echo out the standard output when trying to see something simple like the output of an `ls` command, but just the simple `sh` was all I needed for this. Thank you.