# Jenkins pipeline : awx cli stdout

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline, ansible-tower

In my Jenkins pipeline, I launch a AWX job template with the option --monitor, the main goal being able to follow in Jenkins console what's going on in AWX.

```
 sh ("awx --conf.insecure --conf.host ${ansibleUrl} --conf.username ${ANSIBLE_USERNAME} --conf.password  ${ANSIBLE_PASSWORD} job_templates  launch --extra_vars @ansible_extra_vars_file.json --monitor  $ANSIBLE_JOB_TEMPLATE_ID  ")
```

A similar [post about running an ansible playbook via a shell script in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275712/when-running-an-ansible-playbook-via-a-shell-script-in-jenkins-pipeline-the-ech) had been made. However, the solution proposed does not solve my pb as I did not set returnStdout: true anyway.

The log is displayed in the Jenkins log console only when the Ansible job is completed.

When I launch the "awx job_templates launch"  command directly from the Jenkins slave, the log is displayed in real time in the stdout.

How can I have the stdout being updated in real time in the Jenkins log console ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer was somehow in this post about [Jenkins console output not in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631951/jenkins-console-output-not-in-realtime)

The awxkit package being coded in Python, I just needed to set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

```
sh ("export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1; awx --conf.insecure --conf.host ${ansibleUrl} --conf.username ${ANSIBLE_USERNAME} --conf.password  ${ANSIBLE_PASSWORD} job_templates  launch --extra_vars @ansible_extra_vars_file.json --monitor  $ANSIBLE_JOB_TEMPLATE_ID  ")
```

This allowed me to obtain the AWX logs in real time in my Jenkins console.

Comment: You can add the option "-f human" to avoid having the resulting json being displayed in your Jenkins log